# html table not showing the expected output

Tags: html, css, html-table, attributes, row

I'm new to the concept of HTML tables. I'm facing some difficulties while creating a table. The problem is to make a table similar to [this](https://ibb.co/yfs2rfj)

Here's what I've tried:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" height="200px" align="center" width="200px" style="text-align:center">    
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">2</td>
  <td  rowspan="3" colspan="2">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">4</td>
  <td colspan="2">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">8</td>
  <td rowspan="2">9</td>
  
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>

  </table>
```

I don't know why the cell inside 3,4,8,9 is not doing the row span as expected. Maybe I've made a silly mistake but I don't know what it is. Can someone help me with how to solve it and what could be a better approach to solving the problem? It would be better to use less CSS for conditional issues. Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad English.

**Edit:**
After I've added the height of the 4th tr to 20% in the row of cells inside 8 and 9, it works as expected.

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" height="200px" align="center" width="200px"style="text-align:center">    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">2</td>
      <td  rowspan="3" colspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">4</td>
      <td colspan="2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20%">
      <td rowspan="2">8</td>
      <td rowspan="2">9</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
```

But I don't know why it works now and the first one doesn't. It is better if someone explains it. Thanks again.

Comment: rowspan, and colspan, only span such if they exist. They will not create such to fill up to their number. In your example above there is no row between 5 and 6.

Comment: So I guess it is not possible to create that kind of table using rowspan and columnspan .So what can be an alternative?

Comment: It is not actually "working".  It is still spanning only two rows, but the cell size  is twice what you set the row size to pls some other factors it seems.  To get the effect you want you would have to calculate the % for every scenario.  Note that 20% is not exactly one more row size.  There two ways to get the effect you may want offered below.

Comment: @petern0691 Maybe I have misunderstood you but Isn't the 4th row where 8 and 9 exist the row between 5 and 6?

Comment: Yes, but there was nothing to rowspan over by 3 that was not already being accomodated by rowspans so 6 and 7 "floated" up.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do it:

- fudge a table with a dummy but hidden cell to make it look how you
  want.
- use grid to layout what you want.

Unless you really need a table, ie, the rows and columns mean something more than just positioning, and, for example, they could have row headers and column headers, then grid should be used for layout.

The code below gives an example of both approaches.

```css
/*  CSS for table solution  */

table {
    text-align: center;
    width : 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 35px;
}

.dummy {
    width: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}


/*  CSS for grid solution  */

.layout {
    display: grid;
    gap: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 35px);
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
}

.layout > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 6;
    grid-row: 1
}
.box2 {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.box3 {
    grid-column: 4 / 6;
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
}
.box4 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3 / 6;
}
.box5 {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 3;
}
.box6 {
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: 5;
}
.box7 {
    grid-column: 5;
    grid-row: 5;
}
.box8 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
}
.box9 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
}

/*  Not necessary but centering looks better  */
div > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
Using a table with a fudge:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">2</td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">4</td>
        <td colspan="2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">8</td>
        <td rowspan="2">9</td>
        <td class="dummy"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Using grid:
<div class="layout">
    <div class="box1">1</div>
    <div class="box2">2</div>
    <div class="box3">3</div>
    <div class="box4">4</div>
    <div class="box5">5</div>
    <div class="box6">6</div>
    <div class="box7">7</div>
    <div class="box8">8</div>
    <div class="box9">9</div>
</div>
```